# Custom Options error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new on Magento, and i'm facing an issue after  I've installed it, everything looks ok but in the "new product page" i can't create a custom options. This is giving me an error, and i have no idea what could be wrong with it. Below I've attached a screen-shot of the issue. Have a look.

My Magento version is 1.9.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are enough hints from your error information. when you open "Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php and navigate to line 133, all is clear. "global/catalog/product/options/custom/groups" path may have no value or some other error, it means you need to check node "global/catalog/product/options/custom/groups" in '/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml'. It should list something like below

```
  <options>
              <custom>
                    <groups>
                        <text translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                            <label>Text</label>
                             <render>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_text</render>
                            <types>
                                <field translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Field</label>
                                </field>
                                <area translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Area</label>
                                </area>
                            </types>
                        </text>
                        <file translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                            <label>File</label>
                            <render>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_file</render>
                            <types>
                                <file translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>File</label>
                                </file>
                            </types>
                        </file>
                        <select translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                            <label>Select</label>
                            <render>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select</render>
                            <types>
                                <drop_down translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Drop-down</label>
                                </drop_down>
                                <radio translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Radio Buttons</label>
                                </radio>
                                <checkbox translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Checkbox</label>
                                </checkbox>
                                <multiple translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Multiple Select</label>
                                </multiple>
                            </types>
                        </select>
                        <date translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                            <label>Date</label>
                            <render>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_date</render>
                            <types>
                                <date translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Date</label>
                                </date>
                                <date_time translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Date &amp; Time</label>
                                </date_time>
                                <time translate="label" module="adminhtml">
                                    <label>Time</label>
                                </time>
                            </types>
                        </date>
                    </groups>
                </custom>
            </options>
```

Comment: still giving me the error